# How to run popover using jQuery and Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using `bootstrap` along with `jQuery`.

When I  run the code, the window only appears list of buttons inline, it appears nothing around the buttons, the data contents are gone.

How to clear these kind of problems ?

```
<!--
popover doesnotworking,i am using bootstrap along
with jQuery, when i  run the code,the       
window only appears list of buttons inline, 
it appears nothing around the buttons, 
tha data contents are gone, and 
then how to clear these kind of problems.
-->
    <!doctype HTML>
    <html>
    <head>

    <link type="text/css"  href="C:\Users\USER\Downloads
       \Documents\bootstrap-3.2.0-dist\css\bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="C:\Users\USER\Downloads\Documents
          \bootstrap-3.2.0-dist\js\bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
     src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/language">
    $('.pop a').click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
    $('.pop').addClass('popnomore')
     });

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container" style="padding: 100px 50px 10px;" >
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" title="Popover title"  
          data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" 
          data-content="Some content in Popover on left">
          Popover on left
       </button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" title="Popover title"  
          data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" 
          data-content="Some content in Popover on top">
          Popover on top
       </button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" title="Popover title"  
          data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" 
          data-content="Some content in Popover on bottom">
          Popover on bottom
       </button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" title="Popover title"  
          data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" 
          data-content="Some content in Popover on right">
          Popover on right
       </button>
       </div>

       <script>$(function () 
          { $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover();
          });
       </script>
        </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: `src="C:\Users\US.......` Does `bootstrap.js` even load?

Comment: may you try to load Bootstrap from a CDN, just to check if bootstrap is loaded, as @Satpal suggest.

Comment: Yes it is loaded, i was checked by using "btn btn-primary",

Answer (score 0):

If you want to to show the popover immediately use: `popover('show');`

```
$("[data-toggle='popover']").popover('show');
```